# how to evaluate and work out(5.0+8.1)*(2.0) in my java program?

Tags: java

I'm creating an arithmetic calculator and need to be able to have it answer a question like (5.0+8.1)x(2.0) so far i have create my subclasses according to each mathematical operation i.e. +,-,x,/.
I have got it to work for 2 numbers like 2.0 + 5.0 but i do not understand how i can get it to work for the above expression.

```
class Addition extends ArithmeticExpression{
    Addition(double value1, double value2){
       result = value1 + value2;
       this.value1 = value1;
       this.value2 = value2;
    }

    public double display() {
       System.out.println("Addition Question Is");
       System.out.println(value1 + " + "+ value2);
       return result;
    }

    public double evaluate(){
       System.out.println("Addition Answer Is");
       System.out.println(result);
       return result;
    }


}
```

Comment: This looks suspiciously like homework.  If it is, please tag it as such.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java evaluate string to math expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/java-evaluate-string-to-math-expression)

Comment: Good approach Dmitry! May not be homework... although it looks a lot like it is. :-)

Comment: its not homework its just something ive wanted to try

Comment: You're at least the second poster this week to be working on the identical task.   The previous questioner's problem was type conversion to int, but it's the same task: write a program in java to evaluate expressions.  Coincidental, no?

Answer (score 2):

This is not as trivial as you might think it is. Forget about the mathematical operations. This is the easy part.

The hard part is to *tokenize* your input. I suggest reading :

http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Quick+Starter+on+Parser+Grammars+-+No+Past+Experience+Required

http://javadude.com/articles/antlrtut/

Comment: I think the difficult part is to understand what are AST-s and how to parse them. It it not only about tokenization, ie lexing. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a solution [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-1997/jw-07-indepth.html?page=1). This is an article from 1997, so the author uses a Vector. It will give you a deprecation warning when you try to run it. Ignore it first and fix it later.

[Here](http://www.strchr.com/expression_evaluator) you have a well explained nice C/C++ approach from Siberia. Stick to the description of the solution.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Create another class for multiplication and then do

```
 double result = new Multiplication(new Addition(5.0,8.1).evaluate(), 2.0).evaluate();
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: ive got a class for multiplication exactly like the addition class

Answer (score 0):

Learn more about [Abstract Syntax Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (AST),  [Parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing),  [Name binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give code because it's homework, but it might help if you think of it more that every operation operates on two expressions, so in your example (5.0+8.1) your addition operation operates on one constant expression that evaluates to 5.0, and another that has a constant evaluation of 8.1.  From there, you can think of your multiplication operation as operating on the (5.0+8.1) expression, and another constant expression that evaluates to 2.0.